# How can I customize the code that is generated when I use "Surround with try/catch"?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Each Android developer was stuck with the next situation:

```
public void catchMeThod() {
    throwedMethod();
}

public void throwedMethod() throws IOException{
    throw new IOException("File is missing.");    
}
```

Since `IOException` is Checked exception `throwedMethod` obliges us to handle it.

When I move the caret inside `throwedMethod` and press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>, Android Studio offers me some possible scenarios:

[image: ![enter image description here]

By default I choose the `Surround with try/catch` option and Android Studio generates the next code:

[image]

And my question is: how to change this trigger, to replace

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

with

```
Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Handled exception", e);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Goto `Android Studio Preferences` | `Editor` | `File and Code Templates`
2. Select  `Code` | `Catch Statement Body`
3. Replace the existing template from:

   ```
   ${EXCEPTION}.printStackTrace();
   ```

   with:

   ```
   Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception handled", ${EXCEPTION});
   ```

**Preview:**

[image: Custom try..catch template]

Enjoy the customized template :)

Answer (score 0):

These "templates" are managed by Postfix Completion (Preferences > Editor > General > Postfix Completion > `try`).

Sadly, these are hardcoded into the IDE and cannot be changed. The only way is to replace them manually.

**Change only in current file**

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (or control if you use windows/linux).

In the top bar enter the text to search for, in the bottom bar the text to replace it with. Then click replace all.

[image]

**Change everywhere**

In the project view, right click app and select "replace in path". Fill out the fields and click "find".

[image]

Comment: Tim, I want to find a way to change a trigger(or add). Not to replace everywhere.

Comment: Tim, I'm not able to change block. AS said : this View read-only

Comment: @ssh my bad. It appears this is not possible to change, it's hardcoded into the IDE. You will have to replace them manually..